# Is there a way to see what email I used to create account?

Tags: support

I am trying to log into sharepoint stackexchange but I can't remember what password I used in the other stackexchange sites. Is there a way to see that? I can't find it in my profile.

Comment: Do you use a Facebook, Google or StackExchange login?

Comment: I don't have a FB account and it isn't my Google account, I tried that. So, I must have used an email address.

Comment: Strange. I think @AnnaLear should take a look at this. Might have something to do with the new globlal  login that is being rolled out...

Comment: Thanks rene. I've added a new Google Account which I was able to use to log into the Sharepoint Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 7):

Just to explain what happened here - you didn't have a password set. Back in the day, you logged in with MyOpenID, and for some reason both that credential and a Gmail address associated with the account at the time were removed back in April of 2013.

Glad to hear you were able to add another credential and keep access to your profile. :)

Comment: YES! That is it. OpenId. Thanks for the clarification Anna. And, I know why they were removed. Long story. :)

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason when I try to upvote your response, it shows -1 and not +1. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes go to Profile, Click Edit Profile and settings and then click My logins

Comment: I checked there too. And there is nothing in there other than "Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts".

Comment: It should be there unless you used another method of log on

Comment: you could also add another google account anyway

Comment: Thanks ciaran82. I did just that.... added new Google acct.